# How to get three buttons (1x Left and 2x Right) and then more underneath?

Tags: html, css, button, positioning

(Wow I suck at titles)

Hey, 
I think this is a fairly simple issue. I currently try to build a little self-made Tab Menu. (I know there are solutions out there but it has a reason I want to do it this way)

I want to have three Buttons to begin with (one on the left side and two next to each other on the right) (the links in the example are Buttons in my code). Then underneath these I want to have another set of buttons.

My issue now is that the buttons that are supposed to go underneath the first buttons always go in between the first ones.

```html
<div>
    <p style="float: left">
        <a href="http://hosting127526.a2f33.netcup.net/index.php?company/" class="button">
            <span>Back</span>
        </a>
    </p>

    <p style="float: right">
 <a href="http://hosting127526.a2f33.netcup.net/index.php?weaponry/" class="button">
            <span>Weaponry</span>
        </a>

 <a href="http://hosting127526.a2f33.netcup.net/index.php?Vehcilefleet/" class="button">
            <span>Vehicle Fleet</span>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

<div>
    <p align="center">
        <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
 <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 2</span></button>
 <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 3</span></button>
 <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 4</span></button>
        <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 5</span></button>
 <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 6</span></button>
    </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Moony/Lan5swv0/

Is there a way to easily tell the second set of buttons to not go in between the first set?

I have a feeling that this is such a simple issue but I haven't used HTML and CSS in such a long time.

Many Greetings
Moony

Comment: do you want Button1 in the second row to show at leftmost corner?

Comment: (Ups, meant to call all buttons "Button 1-6")

I want the second row Buttons to be centered on the page (hope that answers the question)

Comment: I don't understand. Kindly add an output format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is as you want? just add clear tab after container it will gone to next line

```css
.nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"> <!-- ADD class nav -->
 <p  style="float: left"> 
  <a href="http://hosting127526.a2f33.netcup.net/index.php?company/" class="button"><span>Back</span></a>
 </p>
  <p style="float: right">
   <a href="http://hosting127526.a2f33.netcup.net/index.php?weaponry/" class="button"><span>Weaponry</span></a>
   <a href="http://hosting127526.a2f33.netcup.net/index.php?Vehcilefleet/" class="button"><span>Vehicle Fleet</span></a>
 </p>
</div>


<div>
 <p align="center">
  <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
  <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
  <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
  <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
  <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
  <button align="left" class="button"><span>Button 1</span></button>
 </p>
</div>
```